# Pyrogram оставить комментарий под постом

Tags: python, telegram, pyrogram

Не могу понять, как через pyrogram можно оставить комментарий под постом? И можно ли вообще это сделать через данную либу?

Answer (score 0):

Это будет выглядеть следующим образом:

```
chat = await app.get_chat(ид канала)
comments_chat = chat.linked_chat.id
message = await app.get_discussion_message(ид канала, ид сообщения)
await app.send_message(chat_id=comments_chat, text=текст, reply_to_message_id=message.id)
```

В первых двух строках мы узнаем ид чата который привязан к каналу(под комменты), в третьей строке находим сообщение с канала в чате и в четвертой оставляем комент.